# lumen/laravel pluck not working in with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have pivot table `vacancy_tag`. I tried different options (value,select, lists and etc), but didn't go further than that. My request:

```
Vacancy::where('id',1)->with(['tags' => function ($q){
            $q->select('tags.id')->pluck('id');
        }])->get()->toArray();
```

return this:

```
"id" => 1,
"title" => "pm",
"tags" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => 1
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => 2
      ]
```

but need this:

```
"id" => 1,
"title" => "pm",
"tags" => [
       1,
       2
]
```

I would like to receive the data result in a query, without using a methods transformation of the collection, if possible.

PS: I slightly corrected the example, need to display all fields of the vacancy + an array of tags.

Comment: I think I would approach this by creating an accessor `getTagIdsAttribute()` then `tag_ids` will return the array of ids. I would not change `tags` as I expect to get a Collection of Tag as it works as default behavior.